# Spring Boot spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES Cannot Serialize

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a configured a datasource which does work in my code, but I cannot get it to report metrics on the Actuator /metrics endpoint.

My setup is the following:

- Spring Boot 1.3.3
- JBoss EAP 6.4 JNDI Datasource defined in JBoss
- JNDI Datasource configured in application.properties for Spring Boot
- Oracle database

It does show up on /heath.
I noticed the following on the /configprops endpoint, which I'm guessing is the issue...although I'm not sure what to do about it:

```
  "spring.datasource.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES": {
    "prefix": "spring.datasource",
    "properties": {
      "error": "Cannot serialize 'spring.datasource'"
    }
  },
```

Like I said, it's "happy" on /health:

```
{
      "status": "UP",
      "customHealthCheck": {
        "status": "UP"
      },
      "jms": {
        "status": "UP",
        "provider": "HornetQ"
      },
      "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 499055067136,
        "free": 285583982592,
        "threshold": 10485760
      },
      "db": {
        "status": "UP",
        "database": "Oracle",
        "hello": "Hello"
      }
    }
```

Here's my application.properties, if that's of any help.

```
server.servlet-path=/*
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/yourfriendthedatabase-ds
spring.datasource.validation-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
# escapes reserved words used as column names (if any)
spring.jpa.properties.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.properties.show-sql=true  
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy

management.security.enabled=false

management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot only provides metrics out of the box for the following types of `DataSource`:

- `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`
- `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource`
- `org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource`
- `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`

To get metrics for JBoss's DataSource, you need to provide a `DataSourcePoolMetadataProvider` bean that returns a `DataSourcePoolMetaData` implementation that's specific to the JBoss `DataSource` implementation.